# ionic: exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException' with camera after capacitor migration

Tags: cordova, migration, capacitor, ionic5

I migrate my ionic app from cordova to capacitor. When I test camera(with cordova plugin) I have this bug. So I test also with capacitor camera and I have the same bug.

```
libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'main thread only'
terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution,

I add this to info.plist

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to your Photo Library for uploading files</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app needs access to your Camera to allow you to take and upload a picture.</string>

<key>NSPhotoLibraryAddUsageDescription</key>
<string>Here write description why you accessing photo library</string>
```